# Color curve - CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I do something like using HTML and CSS:

[image]

Comment: Be more verbose about exactly you want to do.  Tell us what you've tried so far.  Post some code in your questions.

Comment: Could probably be accomplished with `:before` and `:after` using a radial gradient https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Comment: Oh , I thought the community was more open to new users, and tried not to make ironic jokes which in turn may constrain anyone . It's boring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a circle inside the parent container and hide the unwanted section. No need of gradient or `:after` or `:before`

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: #0F7107;
  height: 140px;
  width: 310px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0D3106;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```